# How do I send multiple links in one embed message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am working on an invite command but I don't know how to send multiple links in one message
My code at the moment

```
 const inviteembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Invite Wide!')
            .addField('Invite Me!', "[Click Here](https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=729537680257450104&scope=bot&permissions=8)")
            .addField('Check me out on other websites!',  "[DBL](https://discordbotlist.com/bots/wide)" + "[Discord Bots](https://discord.bots.gg/bots/729537680257450104]" + "(BOD)[https://bots.ondiscord.xyz/bots/729537680257450104]", {split : true})
            .setColor('00FFFF')
            .setTimestamp()
            .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
            message.channel.send(inviteembed)
```

In the `Check me out on other websites!',  "[DBL](https://discordbotlist.com/bots/wide)" + "[Discord Bots](https://discord.bots.gg/bots/729537680257450104]" + "(BOD)[https://bots.ondiscord.xyz/bots/729537680257450104]", {split : true}` It does not make the message thing blue.

It does not work please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just got your brackets confused, I've fixed them and added `\n` to display each link on a new line.

Remember, its this format to embed a link: `[TEXT](LINK)`

```
const inviteembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Invite Wide!')
    .addField('Invite Me!', "[Click Here](https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=729537680257450104&scope=bot&permissions=8)")
    .addField('Check me out on other websites!',  "[DBL](https://discordbotlist.com/bots/wide)\n[Discord Bots](https://discord.bots.gg/bots/729537680257450104)\n[BOD](https://bots.ondiscord.xyz/bots/729537680257450104)")
    .setColor('00FFFF')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())

message.channel.send(inviteembed)
```